# c# WCF DataService + EntityFramework custom stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I have a c# application that uses WCF DataServices with EntityFramework.

Seems everything is working fine, but now I need to implement a custom insert using a Stored Procedure.

I have tried to find any help online but seems there is nothing.

I have my Data Service:

```
[MessageInspectorBehavior]
    public class Security : DataService<VisitAwareContext>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("SecurityUsers", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Sessions", EntitySetRights.All);
            // config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyServiceOperation", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            // Other configuration here...
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true; // TODO - Remove for production?
        }

[WebGet]
        public bool CustomInsert(string customField1, string customField2)
        {
            // here I need to call my stored procedure and pass the fields....

            return true;
        }
}
```

Is there any way to do that? Or someone can recommend me a solution?

I know that you can't stay just using one Server-Client data technology such WCF DataServices and I could add an alternate WCF ADO.NET approach to these scenarios but I would like to keep for the moment using EF + WCF Data Services.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OData actions](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/odata-core/#1041_Actions) with WCF Data Services "[Service Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)". As described in the MSDN article, you may use the WCF [`WebInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) attribute on a method inside your data service class (respecting the constraints given by the attribute).

Inside the method, you can use the [`CurrentDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646632%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property of your data service (inherited from its base [DataService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646779%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) class) to retrieve the Entity Framework [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.aspx).

From there, you may search Stack Overflow on [how to call a stored procedure with the Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework%5D%20stored%20procedure) (or better; read the fine manual, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [WebGet] attribute, use [WebInvoke]. That way you should be able to call the service operation using POST instead of GET from the client. Apart from that, what you have seems correct.

Thanks
Pratik